# Knockout multiple select selectedOptions not selected on load

Tags: knockout.js

I'm creating an edit form for a user, the roles of the user are not selected by default in a multiple select.

There are 2 application roles: "Administrator" and "Moderator". The sample user has 1 role "Administrator". This one is not selected by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/jgT8s/4/

html:

```
<form data-bind="with: user">
    <select id="selectRoles"
        data-bind="options: $root.allRoles, selectedOptions: Roles, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id'"
        multiple="true"
        size="5">
    </select>
</form>
```

js:

```
var User = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(1337);
    self.Username = ko.observable('pietpaulusma');
    self.Roles = ko.observableArray([{ Id: 1, Name: 'Administrator' }]);
};

function UserViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.user = ko.observable(new User());
    self.allRoles = ko.observableArray([{ Id: 1, Name: 'Administrator' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Moderator' }]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel());
```

**UPDATE**
created an dependentObservable and mapped that one to selectedOptions

```
self.RoleIds = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.Roles(), function (role) {
            return role.Id;
        });
    });
```

working version: http://jsfiddle.net/jgT8s/5/

Comment: That's a great tip regarding the dependentObservable.. shame we have to go to such lengths..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Roles` contains "full" object whereas it should contain only the value part:

```
self.Roles = ko.observableArray([1]);
```

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vkda5/

Comment: thanx! i've created a dependentObservable that returns all the Ids of Roles http://jsfiddle.net/jgT8s/5/ would be nice if knockout mapped the objects with the optionsValue property tho.

Comment: @Bas: I agree - using `optionsValue` consistently would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Knockout needs to compare selected options by values, which is `Id` in this case: `optionsValue: 'Id'`. And you're passing an array of `Role` objects. You need to pass array of `Id` instead:

```
var User = function () {
    ...
    self.Roles = ko.observableArray([1]);
};
```

Comment: Answered first but not the accepted answer.. ?? +1 from me.

Comment: Does anyone know how to have objects instead only Ids?

Comment: The key thing here is that by specifying the `optionsValue:` you are setting exactly what the list is bound to even if your `options:` binding points to an array of objects, took me a while to grasp this.